# Kogito Apps with distributed transaction with data index

Tags: kogito

We are using kogito runtime and data index. Need to have distributed transaction management for the process.
What we see is domain object is persisted and process instance is not created if there is issue with Kafka. Similarly process instance gets created but not. Domain objects if there is issue with kogito runtime persistence.

What can we do for correct rollback for the apps.

How to enable dostributed transaction manageme t between kogito apps and kogito runtime especially data index.

Answer (score 0):

Processing of Kafka messages in Data Index is transactional so it should be all or nothing for domain and process instance. That means, for every message received from Kafka it will update the domain and process instance in the same transaction to avoid inconsistencies, if that is not working somehow we need to investigate.

As for consistency with the runtime, I would recommend looking into the outbox pattern using Debezium there is an example using MongoDB (https://github.com/kiegroup/kogito-examples/tree/stable/kogito-quarkus-examples/process-outbox-mongodb-quarkus). We plan to extend that to other DBS such as PostgreSQL.

Which persistence backend are you using? And Kogito version?

Comment: we are using mongodb in our use case. Will check the outbox pattern. There is a limitation as our mongodb services do not provide access to admin db and clusterroles. We are trying to figure debezium use. Will update if we are able to use the same